# React Native: how to share session cookie between the user-agent used during login and axios?

Tags: react-native

I would like to implement login in React Native app using the BFF pattern where requests are secured with sessions on a backend (not using `react-native-app-auth` which requires to configure the React Native app as a public OAuth2 client).

I already have a working BFF (it can maintain sessions for frontends written with Angular or Next.js, retrieve and store OAuth2 tokens, and then replace session cookies with access tokens before forwarding a request from frontends to REST APIs configured as OAuth2 resource server).

For login, I tried to redirect the user with `Linking.openURL(...)` at an URI provided by the BFF. This opens the system browser (Chrome) and authorization code flow is successful (the OAuth2 client on the server gets access and ID tokens), but after I'm redirected back to the native application (through a deep-link), I have no idea how to:

- retrieve the session cookie used during the login process
- send this cookie with my axios requests to authorize it

Has anyone managed to achieve something similar? If yes, how?

I imagine that opening the link to the authorization endpoint with the HTTP context of the native app is a way to go, but I have no idea of what should be used for that :/

Comment: Do I understand correctly, your app send a auth request and get a response/deep link with the token and you don't know how to access the token?

Comment: No, the app redirects to the authorization server, but the authorization code is sent to the BFF (on the server), which fetches the tokens. This is one the important points of the BFF pattern: tokens are stored on the server and never reaches the web browser or native application. Exchange is between the frontend and the BFF is secured with session cookie, reason for me looking for a mean to retrieve the cookie used during the authorization code flow (or just to have it sent with further requests if the cookie is http-only).