# `react-native-app-auth`: how to use a verified app link instead of a custom scheme?

Tags: android, react-native

After [failing to implement the BFF pattern with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76516082/619830), I'm trying to configure `react-native-app-auth`, which is the recommended way to configure OAuth2 in the [official doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#oauth2-and-redirects).

The trouble I face now is that [according to the doc](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#android-setup), this lib seems to support only custom scheme, when I'd like to use [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#android-app-links) or iOS Universal Links (which are quite better when it comes to UX and security).

Is there a way to have "web" links to a React Native app for `react-native-app-auth` callback after successful login?